# Python yield (migrating from Ruby): How can I write a function without arguments and only with yield to do prints?

Tags: python, ruby, generator, yield, proc

I've been converting Ruby code to Python code and now I'm stuck with this function that contains `yield`:

```
def three_print():
    yield
    yield
    yield
```

I would like to call the function and tell it to print "Hello" three times because of the three `yield` statements. As the function does not take any arguments I get an error. Can you tell me the easiest way to get it working? Thank you.

Comment: Other than adding an argument?

Comment: Note that the `yield` keyword in Ruby has very different behavior than the `yield` keyword in Python.

Comment: **Note to potential answers:** Please read the question carefully. The OP is looking to translate code with _specific semantics_ from ruby to Python. While answers like `print('Hello\n'*3)` are technically correct, they are missing the most important point: The behavior of the `yield` keyword in Ruby vs Python.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`yield` in Ruby and `yield` in Python are two very different things.

In Ruby `yield` runs a block passed as a parameter to the function.

Ruby:

```
def three
  yield
  yield
  yield
end

three { puts 'hello '} # runs block (prints "hello") three times
```

In Python `yield` throws a value from a generator (which is a function that uses `yield`) and stops execution of the function. So it's something completely different, more likely you want to pass a function as a parameter to the function in Python.

Python:

```
def three(func):
  func()
  func()
  func()

three(lambda: print('hello')) # runs function (prints "hello") three times
```

**Python Generators**

The code below (code you've provided) is a generator which returns `None` three times:

```
def three():
   yield
   yield
   yield

g = three() #=> <generator object three at 0x7fa3e31cb0a0>
next(g) #=> None
next(g) #=> None
next(g) #=> None
next(g) #=> StopIteration
```

The only way that I can imagine how it could be used for printing "Hello" three times -- using it as an iterator:

```
for _ in three():
    print('Hello')
```

**Ruby Analogy**

You can do a similar thing in Ruby using `Enumerator.new`:

```
def three
  Enumerator.new do |e|
    e.yield # or e << nil
    e.yield # or e << nil
    e.yield # or e << nil
  end
end

g = three
g.next #=> nil
g.next #=> nil
g.next #=> nil
g.next #=> StopIteration

three.each do
  puts 'Hello'
end
```

Comment: You should mention that the Ruby equivalent to the [Python `yield` **keyword**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) is the [Ruby `Enumerator::Yielder#yield` **method**](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-c-new) (also aliased to `Enumerator::Yielder#<<`, and neither properly documented, unfortunately).

Answer (score 7):

`yield` in Python doesn't work like in Ruby. In particular, it doesn't mean "execute the block argument here". This function will never execute callbacks.

In Python, `yield` is for creating iterators (specifically generators), and the function you've posted will return an iterator that produces `None` 3 times. You can loop over the iterator and print "Hello" for each value, ignoring the `None`:

```
for _ in three_print():
    print("Hello")
```

which is the closest you'd get to the Ruby behavior, but still fundamentally different in terms of underlying mechanics.

Alternatively, if you *do* want a function that will execute a callback 3 times, that would be

```
def f(callback):
    callback()
    callback()
    callback()
```

and you could call it as

```
f(lambda: print("Hello"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
def three_print():
  yield"Hello\n"*3
print(''.join(list(three_print())))

# Hello
# Hello
# Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can yield in a loop:

```
def hello():
   for i in range(3):
      yield "hello"

print(list(hello()))
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'hello', 'hello']
```

In Python3.3 and greater, you can use the `yield from` statement:

```
def hello():
   yield from ["hello" for i in range(3)]

print(list(hello()))
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'hello', 'hello']
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: The `yield from` syntax is only available in Python _3.3_ and greater. See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/).

Comment: @ChristianDean Thanks! I did not know that. Fixed now.

Comment: _Eh_, still not exactly correct. It's only available in Python 3.3 and greater. Any Python 3.x version will not work. It needs to specifically be Python 3.3+.

Answer (score 0):

```
def three_print():
  yield("Hello")
  yield("Hello")
  yield("Hello")
```

since there are three `yields`, you need to call `three_print().next()` three times to get the `"Hello"` string to output